# buildin wheel error while using gdal through pip install

Tags: python, gdal

i am trying to install gdal on python using cmd. i used c:\pip install gdal but the following error message appears:

> Failed building wheel for gdal

and at the end detail error message appears,

> "Command "c:\users\usman\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\usman\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3a_vv1uf\gdal\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\usman\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ig9j7gkj\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\usman\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3a_vv1uf\gdal\"

i have also downloaded some gdal .whl fiiles and tried them in my path but no result. and following message appears,

> Requirement 'c:\user\usman\downloads\GDAL-2.4.1-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
>   Processing c:\user\usman\downloads\gdal-2.4.1-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
>   Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\user\usman\downloads\GDAL-2.4.1-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl'"